# Что такое join bomb?

Tags: sql, join, реляционная-модель

Я так понял есть проблемы, которые очень плохо решаются с помощью реляционной теории, можете пожалуйста привести подробный пример что такое join-бомба?

Comment: http://blog.bruggen.com/2013/01/demining-join-bomb-with-graph-queries.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

Join-бомба — это специально сконструированный SQL-запрос, который использует множество соединений (join) между таблицами для создания огромного объема данных. Этот метод может привести к серьезным проблемам производительности и даже к сбоям в работе сервера базы данных.

Предположим, у нас есть следующие таблицы в базе данных:

1. Таблица "users" с информацией о пользователях (id, name, email).
2. Таблица "orders" с информацией о заказах (id, user_id, product_id, quantity).
3. Таблица "products" с информацией о продуктах (id, name, price).

Теперь предположим, мы хотим вывести общую стоимость всех заказов для каждого пользователя. Мы могли бы использовать SQL-запрос с несколькими соединениями (join):

```sql
SELECT users.name, SUM(products.price * orders.quantity) AS total_cost
FROM users
JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user_id
JOIN products ON orders.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY users.name;
```

Этот запрос выглядит логичным, однако если таблицы "users", "orders" и "products" содержат огромное количество записей, то такой запрос может привести к созданию огромного промежуточного результата при выполнении соединений. Это приводит к высокому расходу ресурсов и снижению производительности базы данных, что известно как join-бомба.

Чтобы избежать проблем с join-бомбой, можно использовать более эффективные способы обработки данных, такие как использование подзапросов, оптимизация индексов или кэширование результатов запросов.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)